# C try/except without additional modules

Tags: c, error-handling

I have a C code and I want to print a String if any error has occured during runtime.
in python it will be an easy try.. excpet.. condition. is there a way to do the same in C, without using additional modules?

Comment: You can set signal handlers for when you get segmentation faults etc. Look here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program

Comment: What's a "String"? C doesn't have higher level strings. Unless you are using some pre-made library you have to code all error handling manually.

Comment: @Fredrik a sig faults indicate that something is wrong with your code, you shouldn't try to handle it at runtime. Fix it by fixing the logic, don't try to sneak around it

Comment: @Ahmed I agree, but the OP asked specifically to print a string if something went wrong during runtime, which I interpreted as he meant a crash.

Answer (score 1):

Note: Sorry for my bad english
C doesn't have any concept of exceptions, C++ does but thats beside the point of your question.

In C we use different methods to check errors:

1. Mixed return value:

   - The function that failed returns a special value. E.G malloc returns NULL on failure
   - The function that failed returns a value that doesn't match the case. E.G a function that does something on an array and returns the number of array elements that it has done the job on, you gave it an array of 5 elements it returned 3, definitely there is a problem.
2. Dedicated return value

   - If the function doesn't have something to return but is subject to failure, it can return true/false or a number indicating the state
   - If the function has something to return, it takes a pointer parameter, puts the data in the pointer address, returns true/false or a number inidicating the state.
3. Global error holder

   - The function puts a value that indicates an error in a global error variable
   - The function appends the error to a global array of errors.
4. Signals  (thanks to @thebusybee)

   - You set an error handler beforehand, then call the function, that function ***signals*** your error handler
   - An error handler is passed directly to the function instead of setting it beforehand (in practice this is not a thing that a C programmer would do since there is no standard for lambdas in C it becomes quite a mess, also why pass the handler everytime when you can set it one time)

Note: AFAIK signals doesn't have to be asynchronous

Comment: The "nearest" concept in C to an exception is a signal. You forgot to mention it.

Comment: "please note that c doesn't have real boolean" Then please tell us why `printf("%d\n", (_Bool)42);` prints `1`.

Comment: @Fredrik My bad, also I am surprised that I didn't see (or as far as I can remember) `_Bool` anywhere in the past couple of years since I started learning C. I will remove the "real" part of the answer.

Comment: @thebusybee ohhh how did I forgot the most obvious one. Editing...

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure what you are trying to do, but C has an [atexit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/atexit) function that you could use to try to dump some error to stderr. It is a callback you register with the system but could give access to your error string.